# Can you disable the click of an Ajax accordion in C#?

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion, accordionpane

I have an ajax accordion on my website, and this site has user roles: Admin, Sales Rep, and Customer.. My accordion has 3 Panes, and if the user's role is == customer than I'd like to disable the 2nd and 3rd pane so they cannot open them.

If this is not doable, is there a way to hide the panes. On this page I have a switch case with all the roles that set ability to edit the items in the first pane so I would be able to put the needed code in the customers case.

If there is any code that would be of help I can provide it on request. If something can be cleared up I will do my best to clarify anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well not sure as far as disabling the click of the panes.. but to answer your 2nd part if you can hide them.. You sure can.

```
ajaxaccordionPane1.Visible = false;
```

just what ever your pane names are that you want to hide followed by visible=false;

Comment: yea that will suffice. 
Thank you